# Phone field should not take numerical string and should not be null

Tags: apex

When i am trying to save a record with phone field in account object, then it has to threw an error if the value contains numerical string and null value. I can accomplish this by using validation rule

`OR(ISBLANK( Phone ),NOT(ISNUMBER( Phone )))`

But i want to do this by using Apex class. How can i check the phone field value if it contains numerical string and null value. I tried with following code so many times with out success. May be i was wrong with `if(!Pattern.matches('[+][9][1]+[a-z]{24}+[A-Z]{24}',accs.phone))`

```
public class Example {   

    public Account accs{get;set;}

    public Example(){
     accs = new Account();
    }

    public PageReference click() {
    if(!Pattern.matches('[+][9][1]+[a-z]{24}+[A-Z]{24}',accs.phone)){
    ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'Please enter correct number'));
    }
    else{
    insert accs;
    }
        return null;
    }
}
```

please, Can anyone explain me where i have done wrong with correct code.

Thanks in advance

KS Kumaar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the below code for reference:

```
trigger accounttrigger on Account (before insert) {

for(account obj:trigger.new){

if(obj.phone==null || !(obj.phone.isnumeric()))

obj.adderror('phone is invalid');


}



}
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Abhijeet, 
Can you provide the reference where we can get isNumeric() method????

Comment: Its  a string method.Visit the below link:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm